# How to create a radial Rainbow colored clone using Inkscape or Affinity?

Tags: inkscape, affinity-designer

Say I'm using a single colored square - Red. I want to create a circular (clock style) clone of the square. Each clone being a different shade (from red to yellow and back to red, for example.

Say, 24 clones, 15 degree shift, 360 degrees total.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Maybe a Path Effect might also work in Inkscape. Maybe Rotate Copies or Interpolate?

Used Tiled Clones in Inkscape - didn't work. Tried Using Ctrl-J (Duplicate in Affinity) didn't work. Using most recent versions of Inkscape / Affinity.

Comment: I don't have and am not using Adobe Illustrator, nor do I know what would be done comparatively if I was.  What I did was look at possible solutions using Tiled Clones, looking for essentially something like what Billy Kerr has done below.  Either that or using origin and destination colors in Affinity Designer, and Ctrl-J for copy (modular settings) but, that wasn't working either.  Nothing I could find seemed to cover my specific situation.  And, Billy's is specific to my problem.  Less (mis)interpretation compared to the other questions you refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in Inkscape with cloned tiles.

Use the settings* shown below.

[image]Click to see larger

Set the fill of your initial square to Undefined in the fill and stroke dialog

[image]

Click twice on the square to bring up the rotation handles, then click and drag the rotation centre of the square, using guides and snapping for this is a good idea.

[image]

Create the tiled clones by hitting the Create button

[image]

***Note**: If you are wondering where I got the colour rotate value of 4.16 from, then it's 256/24 = 10.666. And 10.666/256 x 100 = 4.16%